# Testing over a vector of variables and summing over a table, creating new columns in R

Tags: r, vector, summary

I have a table like this:

```
df <- read.table(text = 
                "  Day      city    gender     week
                 'day1'    'city1'   'M'       'one'
                 'day2'    'city2'   'M'       'two'
                 'day1'    'city3'   'F'       'two'
                 'day2'    'city4'   'F'       'two'", 
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I'm computing a summary table like this:

```
daily_table <- setDT(df)[, .(Daily_Freq = .N,
                             men = sum(gender == 'M'),
                             women = sum(gender == 'F'),
                             city1 = sum(city == 'city1'),
                             city2 = sum(city == 'city2'),
                             city3 = sum(city == 'city3'),
                             city4 = sum(city == 'city4'),
                             city5 = sum(city == 'city5'))
                         , by = .(week,Day)]
```

making this table:

```
   week  Day Daily_Freq men women city1 city2 city3 city4 city5
    one day1          1   1     0     1     0     0     0     0
    two day2          2   1     1     0     1     0     1     0
    two day1          1   0     1     0     0     1     0     0
```

But because I have several cities, I would like to use a vector with their names:

```
cities <- c("city1","city2","city3","city4","city5")
```

Note that I have 5 cities in my vector even that one of them has zero occurencies I want it to appear in my final table.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to ensure that R shows you `city5` even though there are no observations with that value, add it as a factor level:

```
setDT(df)

df[, city :=  factor(city,
                     levels = c("city1","city2","city3","city4","city5"))]
```

To avoid the need to write out tests for each level of `city` you can iterate over the levels of `city`, like this:

```
daily_table <- df[, c(.(Daily_Freq = .N,
                        men = sum(gender == 'M'),
                        women = sum(gender == 'F')),
                      lapply(setNames(levels(city), levels(city)),
                             function(x) sum(city == x))),
                  by = .(week,Day)]
daily_table
##    week  Day Daily_Freq men women city1 city2 city3 city4 city5
## 1:  one day1          1   1     0     1     0     0     0     0
## 2:  two day2          2   1     1     0     1     0     1     0
## 3:  two day1          1   0     1     0     0     1     0     0
```